# Error When Using A SearchView to Filter ListView

Tags: android, listview, searchview

> To Start Off...

This is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true" />
    <ListView

        android:id="@+id/lvRelationShip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I am using this code to fill the list:

```
final RelationShipAdapter adapter = null;
sv=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);

        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(text);

                return false;
            }
        });
        lvRelationShipAllUser = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRelationShip);
        lvRelationShipAllUser.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And this is my personal adapter (RelationShipAdapter):

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.relationship_inflater, null);
        View view1 = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.relationship_inflater_nothing, null);

        Holder holder = new Holder();
        //holder.tvFullName1 = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.tvFullName);

        //connectOrDisconnectUser();
        holder.ivPhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        holder.tvFullName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFullName);
        holder.tvFullName.setText(usersInfo.get(position).get(
                Relationship.TAG_USERNAME));
        Log.d("tvFullNameTestIng",usersInfo.get(position).get(
                Relationship.TAG_USERNAME));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(
                usersInfo.get(position).get(Relationship.TAG_PROFILE_PICTURE),
                holder.ivPhoto);

        return view;
    }
```

The Issue is in the first code clippet:

```
            adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
```

In the code above,

> getFilter()

is undefined and (RED) for some reason. Please Help!

***EDIT***:

- Tell me if you need any more information!
- The info in the ListView is in this form: private ArrayList> usersInfo = new ArrayList>();
- Error log:

> error: cannot find symbol method
>   getFilter()

Comment: post the error logs

Comment: can you share complete code for `RelationShipAdapter`

Comment: Sorry for the late response... First, how do I post error logs. Second, Why do you need all the code.

Comment: I added the error log...